# Anchor boxes of Google Object Detection API

Tags: python, google-api, deep-learning, object-detection

I executed object_detection_tutorial on pycharm using google-ssd-with inception v2. 
I wanna see code about making anchor boxes. 
I predicted that I can see variables value in /models/object_detection/anchor_generators/multiple_grid_generator.py if I apply break-point on multiple_grid_generator.py. But, When I executed debug, multiple_grid_generator.py was ignored (jump this section).

When I wanna see the code of making anchor boxes, Where do I apply break-point?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNS2m.png)

Now, Im applying breakpoint on '(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run'
and executing debug to find the code of making anchor box. I guess the code can relate to /model/research/object_detection/anchor_generators folder or  /model/research/object_detection/builders folder.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? Test output? What you're asking is not clear.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) you can see test code. But, I changed 'ipynb' file into 'py' python file. I edited above question. please see again. Thanks! (if you don't see above image, please tell me!